# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in Magento admin

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, multi-select

When I click on Shipping Methods tab under Magento system->configuration->SALES tab I am faced with the following error:

> Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\magento\app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php on line 463

The most astounding thing is that this is a fresh installation of Magento. Can anyone tell me how can I remove this error?

Answer (score 3):

Add to config.xml

```
<global>
    <models>
        <stockindicator>
            <class>Namespace_ModuleName_Model</class>
        </stockindicator>
    </models>
</global>
```

Answer (score 1):

Following this tutorial solve the problem => http://kb.magenting.com/content/20/49/en/magento-error-call-to-a-member-function-tooptionarray-on-a-non-object.html

Go to Magento Connect Manager, click Check For Upgrades. In Actions, upgrade the modules that have the new version, and reinstall these modules:

- Interface_Adminhtml_Default
- Mage_All_Latest
- Mage_Core_Adminhtml
- Mage_Core_Modules

Check mark the "Clear all sessions after successfull install or upgrade", and then click Commit Changes.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve the error:-

1. **Disable Compilation** (`System -> Tools -> Compilation`)
2. **Refresh Cache** (`System -> Cache Management`)

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue and none of the existing answers out there helped. After some trial and error, I discovered my issue was due to a **case sensitive** issue between running on Windows and Linux.

My `widget.xml` file contained this line:

```
<source_model>widget/modeoptions</source_model>
```

My model class was declared as:

```
class My_Widget_Model_ModeOptions
```

This worked as expected when deployed out an an Magento instance running in Mirosoft Azure. When I deployed the same exact code to a Magento instance running on Linux, I received the error.

```
Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in ../includes/src/Mage_Widget_Block_Adminhtml_Widget_Options.php
```

After updating the `widget.xml` to match the class' case, everything worked as expected on a Windows and Linux server.

Updated/fixed line:

```
<source_model>widget/ModeOptions</source_model>
```

Hope this might help some others struggling with this error.

Answer (score 0):

According to webshopapps support all you should need to do is compile through system->tools->compilation. Personally I compiled, flushed caches, logged out and logged in again. It worked.

I had previously tried the update modules method and had to restore from a backup after it broke magento 1.9.0.1

Answer (score -1):

Go to `app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php`

find the following on line 463

```
$optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == ‘multiselect’);
```

and replace it with:

```
if(is_object($sourceModel)){
$optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == ‘multiselect’);
} else {
Mage::log($e->source_model);
}
```

Comment: It's a bad practices to modifiy the core.