# Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in mysite/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

Tags: magento

Hello I'm using magento 1.7.0.2 and if I try to install an extension (personal bar) when i go to configuration it gives me the following error:

Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/System/Config/Form.php on line 463

line 463:$optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');

Can you heelp me?

```
                    $sourceModel = Mage::getSingleton($factoryName);
                if ($sourceModel instanceof Varien_Object) {
                    $sourceModel->setPath($path);
                }
                if ($method) {
                    if ($fieldType == 'multiselect') {
                        $optionArray = $sourceModel->$method();
                    } else {
                        $optionArray = array();
                        foreach ($sourceModel->$method() as $value => $label) {
                            $optionArray[] = array('label' => $label, 'value' => $value);
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    $optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == 'multiselect');
                }
                $field->setValues($optionArray);
            }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Call to a member function toOptionArray() on a non-object in Magento admin](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16053666/fatal-error-call-to-a-member-function-tooptionarray-on-a-non-object-in-magent)

Answer (score 6):

Go to app\code\core\Mage\Adminhtml\Block\System\Config\Form.php

find the following on line 463

```
$optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == ‘multiselect’);
```

and  replace it with:

```
if(is_object($sourceModel)){
$optionArray = $sourceModel->toOptionArray($fieldType == ‘multiselect’);
} else {
Mage::log($e->source_model);
}
```

Comment: Disabling compiler (System > Tools > Compiler) seems to be the most common fix to this issue, but the above is the only thing that worked for me.

Comment: I was facing this error in a theme I bought from themeforest , after making the change above I'm able to see my theme options .Thank you .

Answer (score 4):

Its possible when source model now define for some attribute.
Please check  eav_attribute Table source_model field. some entry may be wrong or missing.

Answer (score 1):

In system.xml configuration file 
`select/multiselect`
`modulename/namespace_module_model_somemodelname`. 
Then create namespace_module_model_somemodulename file..
write this toOptionArray() method in your own model (i.e) something like this..
Eg:
public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            array('value' => 1, 'label'=>Mage::helper('newmodule')->**('Yes')),
            array('value' => 0, 'label'=>Mage::helper('newmodule')->**('No')),
        );
    }
suppose modulename->adminhtml/Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config create this function.
Then you shouldn't get the error...

Comment: same if I go to configuration/catalog/mdl list option

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved it with the following steps:-

1. **Disable Compilation** (`System -> Tools -> Compilation`)
2. **Refresh Cache** (`System -> Cache Management`)

Answer (score 0):

Check your file permissions and if extension is installed properly and all files are on the server and if the backend_model for the config field that gives this error exists

Comment: same if I go to configuration/catalog/mdl list option

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with a theme, because a menu for the backend was not named uniquely. In my case, "Magento Theme Bearstore" had the menu entry "themeoptions", but a menu called "themeoptions" was already existing in the m2e module for German Magento!

So do check out which factoryname is conflicted. In my case, I renamed all "themeoptions" (also module names etc.) to "bearstoreoptions" (be careful in match case).